# Determining DB in use from http query

Tags: database, http

Is there a simple way to determine what database is in use behind a website from an external HTTP request?  i.e., I make an HTTP request, get back whatever data is going to come from the webserver - can I inspect any of that and reliably determine that DB in use?  I am thinking not, but figured I would ask this group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The same answer could come from a static file, a SQL database, or a martian telepath.

Comment: Yes, but what *type* of martian?

Comment: The green type, the red ons don't do http

Answer (score 2):

No and for a good reason. If there were it would be a security hole. Unless it is a part of the application functionality.

Comment: Thanks...that's what I thought, but figured I would check.

Answer (score 0):

For most websites, the answer is **no**, however, you may find security holes which reveal this information.  For example, it's possible to get this information if the site isn't coded against sql injection attacks.  For example, try entering the following as your user name:

```
'; select version();
```

On shared hosting system, they often don't have a firewall protecting the database from external connections.

Try the following:

```
telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
5
5.0.51a—Bjb-W
```

This tells you that the server is running MySQL version 5.0.51a.  MSSQL and Sybase also identify their version number before the client attempts to login.

Probably the easiest way is just to ask the webmaster.  If your not a hacker, and the site isn't a bank, they will likely tell you.